# Excel VBA - add a custom number format

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file, generated outside Excel with many percentages. All these percentages have a single decimal place. When imported into excel, Excel adds a second decimal place to the percentages - this seems to be some default format for percentages in Excel. It just adds a "0".

I want to format all double-decimal places percentages to a single decimal point. If I do this manually, by using CTRL+H, Find format/replace format, it goes well. But I cannot do this via VBA/macro, even if I record the macro while doing the replacement manually. The code generated by recording the macro is this:

```
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "0.00%"
Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
    xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
```

The failure happens at:

```
Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
```

After a lot of trial and error, I found that the new format needs to be in the Custom format list. But single-decimal place percentages is not there by default. If I manually format a single cell to the desired format, the macro works. Of course, I do not want to do that with every file.

Any input would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you set a new custom number to the first cell with VBA (`.range("A1").NumberFormat = "0.0%;@"`), doesn't that new custom number format become listed for future use with a bulk replacement operation?

Comment: @Jeeped yep, this seems to solve it :). What exactly does the ";@" do? I am not familiar with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you apply the custom number format to a single cell, it will become 'listed' and subsequently available for future use with a bulk replacement operation. I might recommend using something like,

```
 .range("A1").NumberFormat = "0.0%;@"
```

That particular format mask can be applied to any cell with a percentage or text. If you had a column header label with a text value and applied that CNF, the `;@` portion forces the text to be displayed literally (without change). In this manner you are open to more possibilities *where* you put the first CNF. After it has been used once, it will be available for bulk replacement operation(s) on the remainder of the percentage values.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the simple:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If r.NumberFormat = "0.00%" Then
            r.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly too, although about 2 times slower than the answer @Jeeped gave. It seems that looping through each cell in a large range is slower than the bulk find/replace. Thanks a lot!